# Through AWS ECS, do we run containers inside Virtual Machine (EC2 instances)?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers, virtual-machine, amazon-ecs

I want to confirm if I have this right.

So, most people compare containers with virtual machine. Its always an either container or virtual machine case according to internet articles.

As far as I understand, ECS is a container orchestration service that runs tasks(1 or more containers) inside an ec2 instance (which is virtual machine).

So are we essentially running containers inside virtual machines?

Please correct my concepts, if they're incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. Amazon ECS is a highly scalable, fast container management service that makes it easy to run, stop, and manage containers on a cluster.  Your containers are launched in a cluster of EC2 instances that you manage.
Alternatively, you can choose AWS Fargate to launch your containers without having to provision or manage EC2 instances. AWS Fargate is the easiest way to launch and run containers on AWS.

For more details, please refer to the hands-on [ECS workshop](https://ecsworkshop.com/introduction/) and [ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html).